# Join based on multiple columns python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframes:

**df1:**

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7        col8 
7865                                                                                abc
                                    7269        689                                 def
            8726                                                                    ghi
                                                                        986         jkl
                                                7689                                mno
                        8762                                                        pqr
                                                                                    stu
                        9698                                                        vwx
            3568                                                                    yz
```

**df2:**

```
Scientific value         mapping_value
1                        8726
2                        9698
3                        3568
4                        986
5                        7269
```

I want to match "col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7" column values in df1 with "mapping_value" column in df2 and create a new column called "Scientific value" in df1 which would have entries from "Scientific value" column in df2.

**Output:**

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7        col8   Scientific value
7865                                                                                abc    
                                    7269        689                                 def    5
            8726                                                                    ghi    1
                                                                        986         jkl    4
                                                7689                                mno
                        8762                                                        pqr
                                                                                    stu
                        9698                                                        vwx    2
            3568                                                                    yz     3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Data
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[9698, '',''],'col2':['', 7269, ''], 'col3':['','',986]})
```

[image]

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Scientific value':[1,2,3,4],'mapping_value':[9698,7269,986,304]})
```

[image]

```
#Create dict
d=dict(zip(df2['mapping_value'],df2['Scientific value']))
#Apply dict to dataframe
df.apply(lambda x: x.map(d))
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that:

- all columns in *df1* are of *object* type (actually *string*),
- but all columns in *df2* (including *mapping_value*) are of *int* type.

Because something like join has to be performed between *mapping_value* and
*col...* columns, they must be brought to a common type, e.g. using some
auxiliary object.

So the first thing to do is to create a "mapper" *Series*:

- values taken from *df2['Scientific value']*,
- index taken from *df2.mapping_value*, but coverted to *string*.

The code to do it is:

```
mapper = df2.set_index('mapping_value')['Scientific value']
mapper.index = mapper.index.astype(str); mapper
```

Then define a function to get the *Scientific value* (either a "true"
value or an empty string in the "negative" case):

```
def getScVal(row):
    rw = row[:-1]    # without "col8" 
    rw = rw[rw != ''].to_frame('code').set_index('code')
    res = rw.join(mapper, how='inner')
    return res.iloc[0,0] if res.size > 0 else ''
```

And to generate the new column, run:

```
df1['Scientific value'] = df1.apply(getScVal, axis=1)
```